# Ambiguous tag: [fuzzy]

Tags: discussion, ambiguous-tags

[fuzzy](/questions/tagged/fuzzy) could use some disambiguation.

There are several uses of the tag, including [fuzzy-logic](/questions/tagged/fuzzy-logic) and in the context of images ( [Android Bitmap Saves As Weird Lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926579/android-bitmap-saves-as-weird-lines) and [FadeIn image like Facebook (if not fully loaded, show it fuzzy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089814/fadein-image-like-facebook-if-not-fully-loaded-show-it-fuzzy) )

Comment: I looked at about half a dozen questions with that tag, some were obviously about images, So I retagged those. some were about fuzzy searching, so I retagged them. some I couldn't figure out. I also started a tag wiki for fuzzy saying not to use. with some pointers to better tags, but I probably missed some.