# Synonym suggestion for Fuzzy

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

I came across an interesting question while looking up approaches to string searching. The tag fuzzy appeared, and it caught my eye. Apparently ["fuzzy"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic#Fuzzy_databases) is a real thing.

I would suggest that the tag [fuzzy](/questions/tagged/fuzzy) be a parent synonym for [fuzzy-search](/questions/tagged/fuzzy-search).

I tried to use the suggestion page but did not have a score of 5 in the tag.

[image]

Comment: Related [Ambiguous tag: fuzzy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211181/145673)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [fuzzy-logic](/questions/tagged/fuzzy-logic) would be a better parent, with [fuzzy](/questions/tagged/fuzzy) as the child.  Having said that it looks like the fuzzy tag has been used for both fuzzy-logic and fuzzy-search questions.